# iTunes 11 - Difference between "Play Next" and "Add to Up Next" buttons

Tags: itunes

Is there a difference between iTunes' "Play Next" and "Add to Up Next" buttons? (See screenshot above). They appear if I right click an album and it seems to me that they do the same thing: Adding the songs of the album (or artist) to my "Up Next" line.

[image: https://www.m-i-u.de/images-i73108b6rj8j.png]
<sub>(source: [m-i-u.de](https://www.m-i-u.de/images-i73108b6rj8j.png))</sub>

Comment: Lizzan's answer is correct, and I understand your confusion - I had the same question myself. I was listening to an album, then I used "Add to Up Next" on another album and was surprised that the "Up Next" list had the new album coming up next, with the original album following. I think this is because the original album was navigated to directly, not added to the queue using "Add to Up Next" controls, i.e. only items explicitly added to "Up Next" are stacked.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

'Play Next' adds the song/album to be played directly, 'Add to Up Next' adds the song/album at the end of the songs/albums that have already been added to Up Next. For the first song/album, this will make no difference, but try adding a couple more and you'll see the difference.

In other words, 'Play Next' works as a stack - Last In First Out, while 'Add to Up Next' works as a queue - First In First Out.

Comment: This is true except for songs that are simply in the Up Next list by virtue of their being next in order on the album or playlist you're listening to. So if you choose either "Play Next" or "Add to Up Next" for a song or album, both of those actions will put the song or album to the top of Up Next, as the the current album or playlist was never actually in Up Next.

Comment: @lukethompson True, though I think Apple needs to look at that particular handling of songs.